# SqLite Database in Android is Always being Initialized/null, Unable to Read Data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, null, runtime-error

I was trying to save some data to SqLite so that my app can support in offline mode. But I am unable to initialize SqLite. After following docs, I have the following code so far which behaves weird and I don't know why. Can someone please help me?

```
public class PlayGame extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

    if (database != null) {
        Log.d("check", "Database Not Null");
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from LeaderBoard", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("check", c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2));
        }
    }
    if (database == null) {
        Log.d("check", "Database Null");
        database = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LeaderBoard(Name VARCHAR(200),Score INT,Tap INT);");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO LeaderBoard VALUES('user',5,10);");
    }
    Log.d("check", database.toString());
    }
}
```

LogCat shows Database Null first then it shows a object of database.
First if block is never run, every time it initializes the database and after that again makes it null null in onCreate.

Comment: So... is you database really named **your database name**, as in `database = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);`?!

Comment: no, it's a string, but does it matter?

Comment: Of course it matters. **your database name** is not a valid name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how Android's activity lifecycle works. When an activity is instantiated its fields get default values as any Java object, with references being initialized to null, and then the framework calls `onCreate()` exactly once. When `onCreate()` is called again it is another instance of the same class.

To manage database schema versioning, consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to use SqLiteOpenHelper to initialize properly? @laalto

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html